# How to convert row to column in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure (join two tables and select where condition `@GID`), a want to convert table result from rows to columns. I use a dynamic pivot query.

My stored procedure:

[image]

After I try using pivot

[image]

I want result like this:

```
GROUP_MOD_ID   ADD  EDIT  DELETE  ETC...
---------------------------------------    
G02            1     1    0      ....
```

Can you give me some advice about this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using the batch delimiter to separate your queries. This means the scope of @GID is incorrect. Remove the semi colon after:

```
DECLARE @pivot_cols NVARCHAR(MAX);
```

You don't need to use batch delimiters in this case. The logical flow of the procedure means you can omit them without any problems.

EDIT:

Here's the edited code that I've devised:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GET_COLUMN_VALUE @GID CHAR(3)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @PivotCols NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @PivotCols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ' , ' + QUOTENAME(B.FUNCTION_MOD_NAME)
    FROM FUNCTION_GROUP AS A
    JOIN FUNCTION_MOD B
    ON A.FUNCTION_MOD_ID = B.FUNCTION_MOD_ID
    WHERE A.GROUP_MOD_ID = @GID
    FOR XML PATH (' '), TYPE).value(' . ', 'NVARCHAR(MAX) '), 1, 1, ' ')

    DECLARE @PivotQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @PivotQuery = '
    ;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT A.GROUP_MOD_ID, B.FUNCTION_MOD_NAME, CAST(ALLOW AS BIT) AS ALLOW
    FROM FUNCTION_GROUP AS A
    JOIN FUNCTION_MOD AS B
    ON A.FUNCTION_MOD_ID = B.FUNCTION_MOD_ID)
    SELECT GROUP_MOD_ID, '+@PivotCols+'
    FROM CTE
    PIVOT (MAX(ALLOW) FOR FUNCTION_MOD_NAME IN ('+@PivotCols')) AS PIV'
    PRINT @PivotQuery
    EXEC (@PivotQuery)

END
```

EDIT2:

You should execute this stored procedure like so:

```
EXEC GET_COLUMN_VALUE @GID='G02'
```

Comment: Dear JohnnyBell.It is not work .I create procedure is ok, but i run `GET_COLUMN_VALUE G02`  It error `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'A'.` Please see it

Comment: Looking at your `PIVOT` query, you've replicated the `JOIN` line twice, which will create a syntax error. Put this line before your Exec (@pivot_query) so you can see what it's trying to execute: `PRINT @pivot_query` Also, you should be calling your procedure like so: `EXEC GET_COLUMN_VALUE @GID='G02'`

Comment: So great , same debugging SQL and see error. Thank you . You can try it and share for me . I try but it still not working . `GET_COLUMN_VALUE 'G02'`

Comment: I can't replicate your error, because I don't have any DDL. If you posted sample data and the actual query text rather than images I might be able to help you. When you print the @pivot_query variable, you can see where the syntax is wrong.

Comment: This way, i want to run store procedure as `GET_COLUMN_VALUE G02` and after put `PRINT @pivot_query` , i get error follow `SELECT A.GROUP_MOD_ID, [Add],[Delete],[Edit] FROM 
 (SELECT A.GROUP_MOD_ID,B.FUNCTION_MOD_NAME,CAST(ALLOW AS BIT) ALLOW 
  FROM FUNCTION_GROUP A INNER JOIN FUNCTION_MOD B ON A.FUNCTION_MOD_ID=B.FUNCTION_MOD_ID) 
  FUNCTION_GROUP A INNER JOIN FUNCTION_MOD B ON A.FUNCTION_MOD_ID=B.FUNCTION_MOD_ID 
  PIVOT (MAX(ALLOW) FOR B.FUNCTION_MOD_NAME IN([Add],[Delete],[Edit])) AS P;
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'A'.`

Comment: I've edited my answer since you're struggling to understand what to do.

Comment: Thank JohnnyBell, I have try it , I think lost parameter `@GID` in here  , as same run `EXEC GET_COLUMN_VALUE @GID='G02'` , the result aboth `GROUP_MOD_ID Add Delete Edit
G01  1 NULL 1
G02  1 0 1`. I think should put `WHERE GROUP_MOD_ID='+@GID+'` after `AS PIV'` . How do you think ?Thank man.